# forcing a div to the left

Tags: css

How can I get `<div id="green_bar">` to overlap `<div id="top_header">` and stop at the left edge of the logo? I'm trying to get the green bar to expand to the left when the screen width is expanded, but I want it to stop at the left edge of the logo.

I've tried `position: absolute;` on `#green_bar` but it expands it 100% across the screen.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfgQt/14/**

HTML:

```
<div id="header_bar"></div><!-- Grey line on top -->
        <div id="top_header"><!-- begin top header -->
        <div id="green_bar"></div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="logo">
                <a><h1>info</h1></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div><!-- end top header -->​
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:960px;
}

#header_bar {
    background-color: #424243;
    height: 25px;
}

#top_header {
    padding:0px 0px;
    background-color:#24303d;
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/kGjGG.png");
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow:hidden;
}


#green_bar {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#logo {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#logo h1 {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:258px;
    height:56px;
}
​
```

Comment: Could you attempt to draw a picture of what you want?  Your explanation leaves something to be desired.

Comment: @Daedalus - Sorry for he confusion. It's a little hard to explain. Basically I have a logo contained with a 960px wrapper. Behind it is a background. The background is not in the wrapper and extends 100% of the width. However, I want the left side of the background to be one color, and the right side to be another. So, left side is the green div

Comment: @Daedalus I just noticed my jsFiddle was messed up. Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/hfgQt/14/ You'll need to expand the frame to see the wrapper. I want the green div to fall to the left of the logo. It should expand outward to the left, but be contained by the logo

Comment: The logo isn't working.  Imgur blocks js fiddle it seems.

Comment: @Daedalus Do you see a grey rectangle below the green line? If so, that's the logo place holder. I'm seeing it on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the snippet below.

As I understand your problem, the trick is to get something that is half of (browser width - 960px). That's the amount of the left margin. I used an extra wrapper div to cut out the fixed width (should be 960px, but I changed it to 480px to get it to look OK in jsfiddle). It's `position: absolute` to get it out of the flow. Then the inner div (`#green_bar`) simply has `width: 50%` to cut it down to half the width of both margins put together - the width of the left margin only.

It's hard to understand what you want, so I might have done the wrong thing. Let me know if you need any more help.

```css
header {
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    background:#ffdf85;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d4d4d4;
    background-color:#ffdf85;
}

.wrap {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:480px;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 0, .5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header_bar {
    background-color: #424243;
    height: 25px;
}

#top_header {
    padding:0px 0px;
    background-color:#24303d;
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/kGjGG.png") no-repeat;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}


#green_bar_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 480px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#green_bar {
    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

/*    3.0.0 Logo
----------------------------------------*/

#logo {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#logo h1 {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/kGjGG.png) no-repeat;
    width:258px;
    height:56px;
}

#logo h1 span {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<header><!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<div id="header_bar"></div><!-- Grey line on top -->
        <div id="top_header"><!-- begin top header -->
        <div id="green_bar_wrapper"><div id="green_bar"></div></div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a><span>info</span></a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</div><!-- end top header -->
</header><!-- END HEADER -->
```

Comment: That looks like it might work! I just left my office, but I'll try later tonight and see if that solves my problem. Thanks!